# How to set states separately when an initial state is used to initiate several states at once with useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to initiate several states at the same time using an `intialState` with `useState` hook, and they are set separately on several click events. Check the following example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const initialState = {
        name: 'Tom',
        age: 30, 
        id: 1
    };

    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

    const handleClickName = (e) => {
        setState({ name: 'John', age, id })
    }

    const handleClickAge = () => {
        setState({ name, age: 24, id })
    }
    
    const handleClickId = () => {
      setState({ name, age, id: 2 })
    }
    
    const { name, age, id } = state;

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{age}</p>
            <p>{id}</p>
            <button onClick={handleClickName}>Click 1</button>
            <button onClick={handleClickAge}>Click 2</button>
            <button onClick={handleClickId}>Click 3</button>
        </div>
    )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

This works well, clicking each button would update one state. However the problem is in the `setState` function I have to include all properties like `setState({ name: 'John', age, id })`. If there are lots of key/value pairs, it would be cumbersome to repeat everywhere.

Is there a way to only update the required property without including all properties, like `setState({ name: 'John' })`? I tried `setState({ name: 'John'})` and it replaced the state with only `name` property (`age` and `id` are removed).

Comment: While the existing answers show you how to do this concisely, my own choice would be to simply have 3 different state variables (and therefore 3 different `useState` calls. When using Hooks, unlike in a class, you don't need to have an object containing the whole state.

Comment: @RobinZigmond in my real case I have 20 states, so it isn't feasible to have 20 `useState` calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spread operator for that.

```
setState({...state, name: 'john'})
```

What this does is create a copy of all the other key/values in the state object and only replace the ones you name in the object.

Answer (score 2):

`rest operator` to your rescue:

```
const handleClickName = (e) => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            name: 'John'
        })
 }
```

Alternatively, you could a `class component` whose state updates works as you expect here.